# Relay edges treated as same

Tags: graphql, relayjs, relay, graphql-js

Some of my Relay edges are being treated as the same despite being different data.

For instance, I want to show a list of recommended movies. These movies are recommended based off the fact that there is an actor the user likes.

I expect my data to be like this:

```
{
  "data": {
    "movies": {
      "edges": [
        {
          "node": {
            "name": "Cool Movie 1",
            "myActor": {
              "name": "John Smith"
            }
          },
          "node": {
            "name": "Cool Movie 1", <- Same as movie above, different actor
            "myActor": {
              "name": "Mary Smith"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Yet it returns the same actor for both node.

In my **resolve()** I return a Relay connection. 
The **edges** are generated like this:

```
let edges = movieIdAndActorIdPairs.map(({movieId, actorId}) => ({
      cursor: //,
      node: async () => {
          const dataRequirements = [getMovie(movieId), getActor(actorId)]
          let [movie, actor] = await Promise.all(dataRequirements)
          movie.myActor = actor
          return movie
      }
}))
```

When I log my `edges` it shows the correct `myActor` but when I log the `myActor` field on my `Movie` type, they both become *John Smith*.

Comment: Have you verified that you're getting the expected value for `actor` *inside* your loop? (ie. on the server, not on the client)

Comment: @wincent Yes, I `console.log`ed right under the Promise, as well as in the resolver method for the field 'myActor' in my 'Movie' type, which is where the code continues immediately after returning.

Comment: do the two movie nodes have the same id? looks like

Comment: @marktani Yes, since they are the same movie... is this batching based on ID a documented feature of GraphQL? I'm aware of Dataloader, but at this point it's far ahead in the stack where it shouldn't be a concern. This is the first time I'm returning data like this where, from the top level, it may seem like the data are the same, but in fact have different data passed to them...

Comment: you could have another nested movie like you do with myActor

Comment: so for really "the same" means the same id. cannot have the same node with two different states at the same time, right?

Comment: @marktani Thanks for the great suggestion. I thing I was trying to express our design with code... Basically we list the movie for each actor, but the API side doesn't really need to give data in that format. Will see how giving movies with the actors grouped together, then iterating on the client side through the actors for each movie and appending event data to each will work. But it is weird that it doesn't work even though the cursor and ID of event are now unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to everyone that helped me out.

I've tried the suggested methods, but couldn't get the desired data set.

So I took this approach where an `actorMovie` contains separate fields for `actor` and `movie`:

```
{
  "data": {
    "actorMovies": {
      "edges": [
        {
          "node": {
            "movie": {
              name: "Cool Movie 1",
            },
            "myActor": {
              "name": "John Smith"
            }
          },
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

This removes the worry of overlapping IDs causing unintentional groupings.

Answer (score 0):

The individual `node` lacks an `id` field, which resulted in a common id value for all nodes (movies). When Relay store is updated, it stores two nodes with the same ID and the same content.

Set id of each node here:

```
  node: async () => {
      const dataRequirements = [getMovie(movieId), getActor(actorId)]
      let [movie, actor] = await Promise.all(dataRequirements)
      movie.myActor = actor
      movie.id = movieId + actorId;
      return movie
  }
```

Comment: I've tried this, as well as making my cursor a combination like `${movieId}:${actorId}`, but it still seems to treat them as the same.